# Implement move semantics for my own std::vector

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

How do I implement move schematics for std::vector given the internal fields data, size and capacity?
How can I make this thread safe?

```
#include <utility>

class vec {
public: 
    vec(vec&& o) : size(o.size), capacity(o.capacity), data(std::move(o.data))
    {}

    vec& operator=(vec&& o)
    {
        if (this != &o) {
            size = o.size;
            capacity = o.capacity;
            delete[] data;
            data = o.data;
            o.data = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    vec(vec&) = delete;                         // disable copying
    vec& operator=(vec&) = delete;  
    vec& operator=(vec&) const = delete;

    int* data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};
```

Comment: Define "thread safe". Specifically, what do you expect to be thread safe about moving?

Comment: By thread-safe I mean: I want N threads to be able to call the move methods at the same time.

Comment: On the same object or on different objects? And I'm talking about both source and destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points:

- I don't think you would use `std::move` on a raw pointer. You would just
  assign the pointer over using `data = o.data` and then set the old one to null `o.data = nullptr` manually.
- By definition, if you are moving an object, you are making an assumption that no other threads are going to use the object you are moving otherwise you should not be moving it, therefore you would not enforce thread safety in a move assignment operator, you would ensure thread safety in the rest of your code.

Comment: I amended the code to reflect your comments.
It would be nice to have the thread safety build into the object, maybe via a swap and compare function?

Comment: Like I said, trying to make move assignment thread safe is conceptually flawed. Something that might be applicable to you would be something similar to the `swap` method on the `std::vector`. If you want to use a CAS operation to achieve thread safety, I would ask that as a separate question in SO, otherwise you could just use a `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` to achieve thread safety, but you will then need to consider thread safety of all internals (and possibly your iterators depending on the level of functionality you are trying to implement).